# Facebook sharing link is not showing a thumbnail of the images within the post?

Tags: posts, facebook

Usually facebook share gets an image from the site to post and shows it as thumbnails.

If you press the share this on facebook link in my test page it doesn't.

This is my test site: http://alexchen.info/taiwantalk/

This is the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Front Page
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Prominent
 * @since Prominent 1.0
 */
get_header(); ?>
<div id="tagline">
    <div class="container">
    </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- #tagline -->
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="mainbar">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="content-block-2">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" target="blank">Share on Facebook</a>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */ ?>
            <?php if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
                <?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; Older posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
                <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts &rarr;', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- #mainbar -->
    </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- #content-bottom -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**EDIT:**

I added all necessary meta tags and links:

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="title" content="Article headline here" />
<meta name="description" content="Article summary here" />
<title><?php
    /*
     * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
     * We filter the output of wp_title() a bit -- see
     * twentyten_filter_wp_title() in functions.php.
     */
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="image_src" href="http://alexchen.info/taiwantalk/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/cheating.png" />
```

But this is the only thing that is shown:

> asdasd | Taiwan Talk
>   http://alexchen.info/taiwantalk/2011/03/...
>
> You may use these HTML tags and
>   attributes:

any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same issue. I used the URL linter, where the image shows correctly. However, when I link the page the thumbnail does not show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://alexchen.info/taiwantalk/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/cheating.png" />`

Visit http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and see "Step 2 - Get Open Graph Tags"

There's also a lot of WP plugins out there that can help you to generate Open Graph tags.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook caches information about a page when share it.  You can use the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) to refresh the cache and see exactly what info FB has on your page. The linter has helped me quite a bit with these issues.

Comment: I had this same issue the other day after updating to a new image, then I noticed today that it shows the new image so I was thinking it must be cached, thanks for verifying that

Answer (score 1):

You need to Add a image source meta tag to the head tag of your document.

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://site.com/image.jpg" />
```

Comment: Still doesn't work please see my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Open Graph is the way to go! Put the open graph meta tags, and then use Facebook Linter to check if all your data comes through right.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the 'http://www." from the front of the URL as well as the last trailing '/' and it should work. Fixed it for me!

Answer (score -3):

I tried the OG Tags and pretty much everything else that has ever been advised all over the internet and none of it worked. It just about drove me crazy, so in the end I wrote my own little bit of amateur code which finally works. It simply posts the Title and the image, with an excerpt onto the users fb wall. It worked for me so I put up a tutorial for it  https://www.facebook.com/imperialantiques?v=app_100783790015943

Comment: Sending others off to somewhere you can't even view without jumping through hoops makes very poor answer by Stack Exchange standards. Please consider posting full info here or making it accessible in other way to all visitors of the site. Otherwise it's likely to get deleted.

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.